# MacBook Unibody 2009 Battery Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, unibody

I have a MacBook Unibody 2009 and am facing a weird issue.

My laptop only works when it's connected to a power source but not on battery.

As most of us would, I thought the battery was gone so I bought a new battery. However, after charging it I still had the same issue.

So, I took it to a repair person whom I know and he told me it's some issue on the motherboard. Now I am not very sure how accurate his diagnosis is.

Does anybody here know of or have a similar issue concerning MacBooks? Can anyone share some information on this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the SMC?

**Reset the SMC**

It's easy to reset your computer's System Management Controller (SMC). The instructions for resetting the SMC on a MacBook depends on two things:

- Does your device run from a removable battery? **(Yes in your case)**
- Does your device run from a built-in battery?

Now, for the sake of others who may come here looking for answers to the same issue, I will provide the process for both.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBooks etc that you can remove the battery from, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

**For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Hope this helps. Please report back and let us know.

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). It may be worth you also resetting this. Here’s how to:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

Comment: Now that, sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I already tried SMC Reset but it didn't worked.

Comment: I just tried your other 2 ways, but looks like those 2 are also not the solution for my problem. Thanks for your response though, appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with either your SMC, or the LION charging system, it is possible that the computer is not aware of the battery, boot up the computer, and click on the battery icon, does it give a battery status?

Take it to a professional! Apple computers are complicated, and you should not be trusting your very expensive Mac with someone you do not trust.

No doubt Louis Rossman will have a video about this...

Comment: Its showing me the charged percentage, everything looks perfect but its just not working when I removed the power source.

Comment: does it say that the battery needs replacing?

It does sound like an issue with the SMC, did you try reseting it? have you tried contacting Ifixit?